# Como añadir botones a un SpriteBatch en libGDX?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

Con el SpriteBatch solo se recoger cuando tocas en cualquier parte de la pantalla pero no en ningun sitio especifico o varios botones. No estoy utilizando stage.

```js
    private static final int ESPACIO_TUBO=125;
    private static final int CONTADOR_TUBOS=4;
    private static final int SUELO_ABAJO=-100;
    //Nave
    private Nave nave;
    //Fondo
    private Texture bg;
    //Suelo
    private Texture suelo;
    private Vector2 suelo1,suelo2;
    //Puntuacion
    private Label pts;
    private Label.LabelStyle ptsStyle;
    //Pause
    private TextButton.TextButtonStyle pauseStyle;
    private int puntuacion;

    //boolean para salir a puntuacion
    private boolean juegoAcabado;

    //GameOver
    private Texture finJuego;

    private Array<Tubo> tubos;

    //Stage
    protected Stage stage;



    protected PlayState(GameStateManager gam,int idNave) {


        super(gam);
        nave= new Nave(20,75,idNave);
        cam.setToOrtho(false, ShipAdventure.GAME_WIDTH/2,ShipAdventure.GAME_HEIGHT/2);

        // Creem el viewport amb les mateixes dimensions que la càmera
        StretchViewport viewport = new StretchViewport(ShipAdventure.GAME_WIDTH/2,ShipAdventure.GAME_HEIGHT/2,cam);

        //Creem l'stage i assignem el viewport
        stage = new Stage(viewport);


       //Creamos la textura del fondo
        bg=new Texture("springfield.png");
        bg.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

        //Creamos las texturas y fisicas del suelo
        suelo = new Texture("ground.png");
        suelo1=new Vector2(cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth/2 -30,SUELO_ABAJO);
        suelo2 = new Vector2((cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth/2)-30+suelo.getWidth(),SUELO_ABAJO);

        //Creamos la textura de Fin del juego
        finJuego= new Texture("gameover.png");


        //Creamos el label del puntuacion
        ptsStyle=new Label.LabelStyle();
        ptsStyle.font=AssetManager.font;

        //Creem el textbutton de pause

        pauseStyle=new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        pauseStyle.font=AssetManager.font;

        puntuacion=0;

        //Creamos el array de tubos
        tubos=new Array<Tubo>();

        //Añadimos 4 tubos al array de tubos
        for (int i=1;i<=CONTADOR_TUBOS;i++){

             tubos.add(new Tubo((i+1)*(ESPACIO_TUBO+Tubo.ANCHO_TUBO)));
        }
        juegoAcabado=false;

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    }

    @Override
    protected void handleInput() {


        if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
            if (juegoAcabado)
                gam.set(new PuntuacionState(gam,puntuacion));
            else
                nave.salto();
        }




    }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {

        handleInput();
        updateSuelo();
        nave.update(dt);
        cam.position.x=nave.getPosition().x +100;
        for (Tubo tubo:tubos){
            if(cam.position.x-(cam.viewportWidth/2)> tubo.getPosTuboArriba().x+tubo.getTuboArriba().getWidth()){
                tubo.reposicionar(tubo.getPosTuboArriba().x+((Tubo.ANCHO_TUBO+ESPACIO_TUBO)*CONTADOR_TUBOS));
            }

            //Si la nave choca con un tubo
            if(tubo.choque(nave.getLimites())) {

                nave.choque=true;
                juegoAcabado=true;


                //return;
            }else{

                if(nave.choque!=true)
                puntuacion++;

            }

            //Si la nave toca el suleo
            if(nave.getPosition().y<=suelo.getHeight()+SUELO_ABAJO-8){
                nave.choque=true;
                juegoAcabado=true;
                //return;
            }

        }

        cam.update();


    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {

        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        sb.begin();


        //Dibujamos el fondo
        sb.draw(bg,cam.position.x-(cam.viewportWidth/2),0,cam.viewportWidth,cam.viewportHeight);

        //Dibujamos la nave
        sb.draw(nave.getNave(),nave.getPosition().x,nave.getPosition().y,nave.NAVE_ANCHO,nave.NAVE_ALTO);
        for (Tubo tubo:tubos) {
            sb.draw(tubo.getTuboArriba(),tubo.getPosTuboArriba().x,tubo.getPosTuboArriba().y);
            sb.draw(tubo.getTuboAbajo(),tubo.getPosTuboAbajo().x,tubo.getPosTuboAbajo().y);
        }

        //Colocamos la puntuacion
        AssetManager.font.draw(sb,puntuacion+"",cam.position.x-(cam.viewportWidth/2)+10,cam.viewportHeight-10);
        //Dibujamos el suelo
        sb.draw(suelo,suelo1.x,suelo1.y);
        sb.draw(suelo,suelo2.x,suelo2.y);

        //Si ha acabado el juego pintamos un GameOver
        if(juegoAcabado){
            sb.draw(finJuego,cam.position.x - finJuego.getWidth() / 2, cam.position.y-50);
        }
        sb.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        bg.dispose();
        nave.dispose();
        for (Tubo tubo:tubos ) {
            tubo.dispose();
        }
        System.out.println("Play State preparado");
    }

    private void updateSuelo(){
        if(cam.position.x-(cam.viewportWidth/2)>suelo1.x+suelo.getWidth()){
            suelo1.add(suelo.getWidth()*2,0);
        }
        if(cam.position.x-(cam.viewportWidth/2)>suelo2.x+suelo.getWidth()){
            suelo2.add(suelo.getWidth()*2,0);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: y cual es el código? Revisar [ask].

Comment: Edito pregunta...en esta clase quiero poner diversos botones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería preferible utilizar Stage y [seguir este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488311/how-to-create-a-button-in-libgdx) donde usa la clase TextButton (que proporciona libgdx) a la que le añade un listener para manejar fácilmente los eventos.

La opción menos elegante (también menos reobusta, menos ampliable y menos versatil) sería modificar handleInput() para que obtenga las coordenadas X e Y del último punto que presionó el usuario. Para ello puedes usar los métodos getX() y getY() de [Gdx.input](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#getDeltaX--). Luego habría que comprobar si dichas coordenadas están dentro del area del botón.

Por ejemplo, suponiendo que el botón está en (bX,bY) y tiene unas dimensiones de bW y bH (width y height):

```
@Override
    protected void handleInput() {
        if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
            int pX = Gdx.input.getX();
            int pY = Gdx.input.getY();
            if (juegoAcabado)
                gam.set(new PuntuacionState(gam,puntuacion));
            else if (inBounds(pX, pY, bX, bY, bW, bH))
                System.out.println("Botón presionado");
            else
                nave.salto();
        }
    }
```

La función inBounds sería así:

```
// Comprueba si (pX,pY) está dentro del area cuadrada (x,y) -> (x+w,y+h)
boolean inBounds(int pX, int pY, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    return ((pX >= x) && (pX <= x + w) && (pY >= y) && (pY <= y + h));
}
```